# Копирование текста из spreadsheets в doc с разделением на абзацы Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

Скрипт переносит текст из ячейки в google spreadsheets в goofle doc, но начало новой строки не являются началом нового абзаца.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли избежать такой ситуации при копировании, или как заменить "принудительное окончание строки" на "окончание абзаца" уже в финальном документе?

```
  function NewDoc() {
  var id1 = DriveApp.getFilesByName("Новое ТЗ1").next().getId();
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById(id1);
  var bd = doc.getBody();

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var vved = ss.getSheetByName("Введение");

  var NaznDoc = vved.getRange('B5').getValues();
  bd.appendParagraph(NaznDoc);
  }
```

Comment: Куча абзацев где, в 1 ячейке? Тогда считывайте данные в ячейке, разбивайте его по переносам текста, и добавляйте каждый отдельно через `appendParagraph`

Comment: @СергейПряничкин , буду очень благодарна, если поясните, как именно можно выполнить вашу рекомендацию "считывайте данные в ячейке, разбивайте его по переносам текста"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если текст с переносами находится в 1 ячейке - то например так:

```
var NaznDoc = vved.getRange('B5').getDisplayValue();
NaznDoc.split('\n').forEach(function(v){
  bd.appendParagraph(v);
});
```